# PostgeSQL + Python 3.9 Query breaks if changed - why?

Tags: python, database, postgresql

In my code, if I change this (working code - so the variables are working just fine)

```
cross_cross_OFR_SQL = '''
                    SELECT DISTINCT ON (racedate) * FROM testview
                    WHERE horsename = %s
                    AND racedate > %s
                    ORDER BY racedate ASC
                    LIMIT 2
'''
cur.execute(cross_cross_OFR_SQL, (cross_detailedhorse, past_racedate,))
cross_cross_OFR_SQLR = cur.fetchall()
```

to this

```
cross_cross_OFR_SQL = '''
                    SELECT DISTINCT ON (racedate) * FROM testview
                    WHERE track NOT LIKE '%KSA%'
                    AND horsename = %s
                    AND racedate > %s
                    ORDER BY racedate ASC
                    LIMIT 2
'''
cur.execute(cross_cross_OFR_SQL, (cross_detailedhorse, past_racedate,))
cross_cross_OFR_SQLR = cur.fetchall()
```

it breaks with this erro *'IndexError: tuple index out of range'*

If I change it to

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (racedate) * FROM testview
WHERE track NOT LIKE '%(KSA)%'
AND horsename = %s
AND racedate > %s
ORDER BY racedate ASC
LIMIT 2
```

it breaks with the error: *'TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str'*

I can not figure out why it breaks inside the python code.
Any ideas?

I want to exclude any tracks that have (KSA) in them.

It works fine in PGadmin4

Comment: are you needing to treat `track NOT LIKE '%KSA%'` as a parameter? i.e. in some queries you need this not like condition, but in other queries you might want to ignore this altogether? or,  sometimes want `track LIKE '%KSA%'`

Comment: @PaulMaxwell In this code, I never want KSA in it - it messes the results  want up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) and [Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) pointed out:

> The % character is special here, because it is a substitution marker (as in the %s you are using). To get a simple % character to pass through, you have to double it.